# MVC4 tie in with google+ login - login failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

I am trying to integrate my MVC4 solution with OAUTH2 Google+ login. I have managed to create my API in google apis to generate keys etc and I have registered google+ client in my AuthConfig.

```
   OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new GooglePlusClient etc..)
```

When I run my MVC app, I get my normal login screen with Google+ as a "Use another service" login.

If I click that button, I go to the Google confirmation page as you might expect. I see that the Google application matches the API I setup. Once I hit "Accept", I go back to my "Account\ExternalLoginCallback\" page, but I instantly get directed to "ExternalLoginFailure".

I haven't set anything else up in my MVC app, is there something missing that I need to do to allow this auth?

Some of the query string items that come back from Google are:

```
state=__provider__%3DGooglePlus%26
num_sessions=1
prompt=consent
authuser=0
code=4/
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: `EternalLoginCallback` isn't a page you are meant to navigate to.  It is the callback page that the API should call, supplying an auth Token.

Comment: Do I simply have to set my return URL in google APIs to be home home/index then? What do I have to decorate my controller actions with to ensure that google authentication has been passed?

Comment: I followed this guide which explicity specified the ExternalLoginCallBack as the return URL: http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/google-signin-for-asp-net-mvc